# Stryker Mutation error: DryRunExecutor.validateResultCompleted

Tags: node.js, vitest, stryker

I am trying to set up Stryker mutation for my Nodejs project. I am new to this and am trying this for the first time. My test cases are written using vitest. I keep receiving this error during my intial test run:

> ERROR DryRunExecutor Initial test run timed out!
> 15:05:13 (58313) ERROR Stryker Unexpected error occurred while running Stryker Error: Something went wrong in the initial test run
> at DryRunExecutor.validateResultCompleted(file://.../vitest_learn/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/dist/src/process/3-dry-run-executor.js:75:15)
> at DryRunExecutor.executeDryRun (file:///.../vitest_learn/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/dist/src/process/3-dry-run-executor.js:95:14)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async WorkItem.execute (file:///.../vitest_learn/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/dist/src/concurrent/pool.js:32:28)
> at async file:///.../vitest_learn/node_modules/@stryker-mutator/core/dist/src/concurrent/pool.js:69:13

I tried increasing the timeout and that was not any help.
The debug logs also do not have any information.